# "missing setter or instance variable" log message occurs initializing NSWindowController with Objective-C in Xcode:

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xib, setter, instance-variables

Here is an abstract I took from an app that already works in which a parent window and sheet are processed. The abstract here compiles, launches, and displays the parent window without having received the message I sent to its text field. The run produces 'missing setter or instance variable' log messages for the text field, the button, and the window itself. For some reason I have not gotten the parent window to be properly initialized, and I suspect I will have the same problem with the sheet window but I can't get past this problem to debug the rest of the app.

I believe I have omitted something fundamental in the process of connecting the window to its File's Owner, even though when looking at the connections inspector for the `.xib` it shows the custom class to be the ParentClass and the various connections are made. I can find no instructions in Apple's labyrinthine documentation nor here in StackOverflow to guide me through the connection process that would allow me to discover the part(s) I'm missing.

Anything you can offer will be gratefully studied.

ParentDelegate.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@class ParentClass;
@interface ParentDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow    * window;
@property (weak, nonatomic) ParentClass * parentController;
@end
```

ParentDelegate.m

```
#import "ParentDelegate.h"
@implementation ParentDelegate
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification  {  }
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)aNotification  {  }
- (void)applicationDidResignActive:(NSNotification *)aNotification  {  }
- (BOOL)applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)theApplication
    { return YES; }
- (NSApplicationTerminateReply)applicationShouldTerminate:(NSApplication *)sender
    { return NSTerminateNow; }
@end
```

ParentClass.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface ParentClass : NSWindowController {
}
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow        * window;
@property          IBOutlet NSTextField     * messageTextField;
@property          IBOutlet NSButton        * proceedButton;
@property (strong)          NSMutableString * parentPropInfo;
- (IBAction) awakeFromNib;
- (IBAction) doProceed:(id)sender;
@end
```

ParentClass.m

```
#import "ParentClass.h"
#import "ParentDelegate.h"
#import "SheetClass.h"
@implementation ParentClass
ParentDelegate * parentDelegate;
SheetClass     * sheetController;
- (IBAction)awakeFromNib  {
    parentDelegate = [NSApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    parentDelegate.parentController = self;
    sheetController = [[SheetClass alloc] initWithWindowNibName: @"SheetClass"];
    _messageTextField.stringValue = @"Click Proceed button";
}
- (IBAction)doProceed:(id)sender  {
    _parentPropInfo = @"Hello!".mutableCopy;
    [NSApp runModalForWindow:sheetController.window];
    // Sheet active now until it issues endModal, then:
    _messageTextField.stringValue = sheetController.sheetPropInfo;
    [NSApp endSheet: sheetController.window];
    [sheetController.window orderOut:self];
}
@end
```

SheetClass.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface SheetClass : NSWindowController {
}
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow        * window;
@property (weak)   IBOutlet NSTextField     * propTextField;
@property (weak)   IBOutlet NSButton        * returnButton;
@property (strong)          NSMutableString * sheetPropInfo;
- (IBAction)awakeFromNib;
- (IBAction)doReturn:(id)sender;
@end
```

SheetClass.m

```
#import "SheetClass.h"
#import "ParentClass.h"
@implementation SheetClass
ParentClass * parent;
- (IBAction)awakeFromNib  {
     parent.window = self.window.sheetParent;
    _propTextField.stringValue = parent.parentPropInfo;
}
- (IBAction)doReturn:(id)sender  {
    _sheetPropInfo = @"Done!".mutableCopy;
    [NSApp stopModal];
}
@end
```

Ultimately I would like to use this mini-app as a starting template for several other apps.

Comment: `ParentClass` and `SheetClass` inherit a `window` property from `NSWindowController`. `awakeFromNib` is not an action method. How is `ParentClass` instantiated?